# Off-canvas navigation using only CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to set up an off canvas navigation using only CSS. Basically I want the navigation to be 20% width and have it behind the main content and then when you click the menu icon, the header and body content will slide 20% off the right hand side of the screen and the navigation will be revealed.

I've almost got it working based off a similar implementation(although they were doing it with width and not positioning) but I am struggling with the last little part.

[Here is my pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AiHpm)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the real problem?

Comment: The problem is that the navigation remains visible even when the "close" button is clicked and the body content is not scrollable(I'm guessing because of the fixed positioning). Thanks!

Comment: You only need to add a background to `.content`, `height:100%` to the `.page-wrapper` and a `left:0` for a smooth transition.

Comment: Thanks xpy, adding a background color to the content fixed the issue where the navigation was showing behind the content, the only thing now is that the animation doesn't seem to be in sync(the header bar seems to animate slower and smoother than the content). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I think it was because the transition was being applied to the header twice since the header is within the page-wrapper which also has a transition. I took the transition out of the header and it seems to work great now. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `background: #fff;` to `.content` style definition. It will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the issue where the navigation was showing behind the content, but the animation doesn't seem to be working together. It seems like the content is transitioning faster and less smooth than the header bar.

Comment: Don't see any problems in Safari (Apple). You can try to change transitions easing method from `ease` to `linear`. If my answer helped you, please, mark it as accepted.